# how to get values from dynamically generated text boxes?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get the values of text box which i generated dynamically on page load and cloned them using jquery....

every text box has a unique id in form of a matrix for eg textboxes of row one have ids textbox11,textbox12,textbox13,textbox14 etc
for row two textbox21,textbox22,textbox23........

is there any way to get the values..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class product_entry : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int count;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            tr.Attributes.Add("class", "tabrow");

            for (j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<Button class=remove type=button>-</button>"));
                }
                if (j == 1)
                {
                    tc.Attributes.Add("class", "sno");
                }
                if (j == 2 || j == 3 || j == 4 || j == 5 || j == 6 || j == 7 || j == 8)
                {
                    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.Style["width"] = "98%";
                    tc.Controls.Add(tb);
                }
                tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            }
            Table1.Controls.Add(tr);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            TextBox aa = (TextBox)Pnl.FindControl("textbox" + i + j);
            Response.Write(aa.Text);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

i want to fetch the values of hundreds of text boxes geerated using jquery by using the loop designed above is there any way to do that

Comment: Assign a unique `ID` to each `TextBox`, then use `((TextBox)this.FindControl(someIDToLookFor)).Text` in your C# code-behind to get its value.

Comment: i dont want to get value iin jquery i want it in c# or code behind so that i can send them to database

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the code I provided is C#, not JavaScript.

Comment: but i want to run a loop because i have hundreds of text boxes 
like this  int count = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    Label l = new Label();
                    
                   string str = "textbox" + i + j;
                   TextBox tb=((TextBox)this.FindControl(str)).Text;
                    l.Text = tb.Text;
                }
            }
is there any way out

Comment: your button click event handler is doing exactly what you asked for... But you have to go down the tree recursive because you add your textboxes to the tablecell

Comment: no but it is not working.......no output

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox aa = (TextBox)Pnl.FindControl("textbox22");
        Label2.Text = aa.Text;}
i tried this to check the result but it gives error stack trace

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 
Line 56:     {
Line 57:         TextBox aa = (TextBox)Pnl.FindControl("textbox22");
Line 58:         Label2.Text = aa.Text;
Source File: c:\Users\akhil\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\cloudpos\product_entry.aspx.cs    Line: 58 

Stack Trace: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Comment: @console how to go down the tree recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a specific css class to all dynamically generated text boxes on page load and by class selector using Jquery you can access all of them:

Use each: `i` is the postion in the array, `obj` is the **DOM** object that you are iterating (can be accessed with the **jQuery** wrapper `$(this)` as well).

```
$('input.SomeClass').each(function(i,obj){

var textboxid = $(this).id;
var textboxValue = $(this).val(); // get text inside text box

});
```

Comment: but how to get these values in C# so  that they can be entered into database

Comment: Simpy the way you do in c#

Comment: id you textbox id is txtBox1 you do like txtBox1.Text to get its value which is in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

If an element has a unique ID, you can query that element using the selector format

```
$('#theExactId').val()
```

In HTML 4.01, IDs cannot start with a number.  If your IDs really are 11, 12, etc you might want/need to prepend at least one alpha character.

If you were trying to get the data on the server side, the variables would be part of the HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

To actually get the value you use

```
$('#theExactId').val()
```

Comment: i dont want to get value iin jquery i want it in c# or code behind so that i can send them to database

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET Literal doesn't add any markup to the page. Therefore you have to wrap your content in some container so that you can edit it via JavaScript:

ou should also consider refactoring all "hard" references to control ids from within your JavaScript code. In ASP.NET, there's the concept of naming containers that will ensure unique ids throughout the page. So if you have a control called

```
 txtName
```

in your Content section, the *real* name of the client (as seen from JavaScript) will be e.g.

```
 ct00_txtName
```

if using masterpages. The prefix is automatically added by the naming container to make the id unique.

Fortunately, every control has a property (server-side) called ClientID which will reveal the actual id that is available on the client. So if you need to access a control from client-side, make sure you always use ClientID property to get the name.
 Like this:

```
var name = document.getElementById('<% =txtName.ClientID %>');
```

Comment: i dont want to get value in jquery or javascript,i want it in c# or code behind so that i can send them to database.is there any way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your C# code that initially creates the text boxes and your jQuery that duplicates the  tags assign a unique name to each tag. So you have tags like this:

```
<input name="textbox1" ... />
<input name="textbox2" ... />
<input name="textbox99" ... />
```

After you submitted the form via postback or Ajax, you can use the Request.Form collection to access the values of the text boxes like so:

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
     if(key.StartsWith("textbox"))
     {
         string currentValue = Request.Form[key];
     }
}
```

If you submit the form using GET, you need to access `Request.QueryString`

Comment: yea the first thing you said is already achieved (all tags have unique id).but can i set the  request.form[key] to be the text of lbel

Comment: The input tags need a unique name, not a unique Id for this to work. When submitting an html form the name of the input tag is used as the key for the Request.Form collection.